# What does err['status'] do?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to understand how to use Express with Typescript. I've created a nice default express project using expression. In it I find the following simple method which I cannot understand and will not compile 'as typescript'

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

In fact the error that atom-typescript and tsc give me is:

> ...at line 31, file /Volumes/MonsterHD/mydev/expressgen/app.tsProperty 'status' does not exist on type 'Error'.

From other research I see that the valid conversion to typescript so that it works looks like this:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   var err = new Error('Not Found');
   err['status'] = 404;
   next(err);
});
```

I am quite confused. I believe I am looking for the Error class in Node. I don't see status as a property on an error. And yet in JS it works. But in TS it does not. Why is this, and what is the meaning of the lines `err.status = 404` and `err['status'] = 404`?

Comment: Confused... none of that is typescript - it's all javascript, and is an example of an express 404 error handler. `.status` isn't a standard property on Error, but in javascript you can easily append any property you like - in this case, the HTTP status code.

Comment: Thanks... That helps! But when i run the top code through ts it gives an error because in the type definition, there's no property called "status". Then, what does the incantation below (err['status']) do then? In js does it mean the same?

Comment: Sounds like whatever is validating/compiling your javascript isn't allowing you to add arbitrary properties to an instance of `Error`. My advice would be to.... not add arbitrary properties to an instance of `Error`.

Comment: You're defining a property `status` on the variable `err`. Just because it doesn't exist by default in the class, doesn't mean you can't extend it. You could also do simply `err.status = 404` (identical), which creates the property `status` on `err`.

Comment: So in js does `err.status = x` mean the same as `err['status'] = x` ?

Comment: Yes, both will do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see status as a property on an error. And yet in JS it works. But in TS it does not. Why is this, and what is the meaning of the lines `err.status = 404` and `err['status'] = 404`?

Basically `express` tacks on a `status` property on an error to provide it as an HTTP response code to the user.

Since `Error` doesn't have this *by default* ... typescript complains. But you can suppress this using the `['error']` hack to be *explicit* that I am *abusing* the error object by adding a `error` property.

Note: From the javascript perspective `foo.bar` *is exactly same as* `foo['bar']`. This is just how *JavaScript* works.

Comment: Great answer as usual :)